# How to use a custom class ArrayList in Android Studio's ExpandableListView, with groups representing objects and children corresponding to attributes?

Tags: java, android

Suppose I make a class of Books, I've tried making an ExpandablelistClass and a CustomExpandableListAdapter Class to display book items and their attributes as their subitems. Attached Below is the relevant code.

```
public class Books {
private String title; //up to 50 characters
private String author; //up to 30 characters
private String genre;
private int year;
private boolean status;

public Books(String title,String author,String genre,int year,Boolean status){
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.year = year;
    this.status = false;
```

...

Expandable List of Data items

```
public class ExpandableListDataItems {
    public static HashMap<String, List<Books>> getData() {
        HashMap<String, List<Books>> expandableDetailList = new HashMap<String, List<Books>>();

        List<Books> Book_list = new ArrayList<Books>();
        Books first_book = new Books("Y", "Fitzgerald", "Romance", 1988, Boolean.FALSE);
        Book_list.add(first_book);
        expandableDetailList.put(first_book.getTitle(), Book_list);
        return expandableDetailList;

    }
}
```

```
public class CustomizedExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> expandableTitleList;
    private HashMap<String, List<Books>> expandableDetailList;

    // constructor
    public CustomizedExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> expandableListTitle,
                                           HashMap<String, List<Books>> expandableListDetail) {
        this.context = context;
        this.expandableTitleList = expandableListTitle;
        this.expandableDetailList = expandableListDetail;

    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return this.expandableDetailList.get(this.expandableTitleList.get(listPosition)).get(expandedListPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return expandedListPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Books expandedListBook = (Books) getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.subcontent, null);
        }
        TextView expandedListTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem);

        // Update the TextView with book details
        expandedListTextView.setText(expandedListBook.getTitle()); // You can customize this based on your requirements

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
        return this.expandableTitleList.get(listPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
        return listPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.content, null);
        }
        TextView listTitleTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
        listTitleTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);
        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ExpandableListView expandableListViewExample;
    ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
    List<String> expandableTitleList;
    HashMap<String, List<Books>> expandableDetailList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        expandableListViewExample = findViewById(R.id.expandableListViewSample);

        // Modify the data retrieval to use Books objects
        expandableDetailList = ExpandableListDataItems.getData();
        expandableTitleList = new ArrayList<>(expandableDetailList.keySet());
        expandableListAdapter = new CustomizedExpandableListAdapter(this, expandableTitleList, expandableDetailList);
        expandableListViewExample.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);

        expandableListViewExample.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), expandableTitleList.get(groupPosition) + " List Expanded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        expandableListViewExample.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), expandableTitleList.get(groupPosition) + " List Collapsed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        expandableListViewExample.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                // Modify the toast message to display book details
                Books selectedBook = expandableDetailList.get(expandableTitleList.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        selectedBook.getTitle() + " by " + selectedBook.getAuthor(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However upon running the code , I get these errors

2024-01-28 17:17:50.991  7958-8057  OpenGLRenderer          com.example.mybook W  Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2024-01-28 17:17:50.991  7958-8057  OpenGLRenderer          com.example.mybook W  Failed to initialize 101010-2 format, error = EGL_SUCCESS
2024-01-28 17:17:51.038  7958-8057  Gralloc4                com.example.mybook  I  mapper 4.x is not supported
2024-01-28 17:17:51.110  7958-8057  OpenGLRenderer          com.example.mybook  E  Unable to match the desired swap behavior.

As well as a blank screen once I run my emulator. I am very new to Android Studio and would appreciate any input.Thank you!